# Background image url does not work with LessCSS

Tags: php, css, wordpress, less

I just started learning Lesscss. I am building a wordpress theme and I am saving the uploaded logo in the wp_options table.
The output of the logo variable would be like http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/logo.jpg
I am parsing the less variables as

```
 $less->setVariables(array(
    'sitelogo' => $options['site_logo'][0],
    ));
```

and in style.less I have

```
.logo {
background: url(@sitelogo);
}
```

This is not working, just outputs `background: url(http)`

Comment: What happens if you `var_dump($options)` in your PHP bit? The `sitelogo` variable obviously isn't getting assigned properly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am getting the output from php. If i echo the url directly in header.php it works. Also i can generate other options like color, width, etc in LESS other than urls

Comment: So `echo $options['site_logo'][0];` echoes the image source?

Comment: yes, but i want it to generate it from LESS

Comment: the issue i have is discussed here https://less.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/31-problem-using-variables-for-background-image-url. If you had a look, you can better understand my problem. Also i tried solutions given by some peoples but that was too not worked.

Comment: You need to escape the variable or you can try striping out [http://example.com](http://example.com) from the URL before assigning it to sitelogo , the URL should be /wp-content/uploads....

Comment: @Anand it turns out fatal error, Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message `'failed to parse passed in variable @sitelogo: /wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/logo.jpg'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add additional quotes: `'sitelogo' => "'$options['site_logo'][0]'"`.

An example can also be found at: http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/#setting_variables_from_php

```
$less->setVariables(array(
  "url" => "'http://example.com.com/'"
));

echo $less->compile("body { background: url("@{url}/bg.png"); }");
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use variables like that in the url().  Try the following.

```
.logo {
background: url("@{sitelogo}");
}
```